# Use NumPy function on arrays containing both numbers and objects

Tags: python, numpy

I have a number-like class where I have implemented the `sqrt`, `exp`, etc. methods so that NumPy functions will broadcast on them when they are in `ndarray`s.

```
class A:
    def sqrt(self):
        return 1.414
```

This work perfectly in an array of these:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.sqrt([A(), A()]))  # [1.414 1.414]
```

Obviously, `sqrt` also works with pure numbers:

```
print(np.sqrt([4, 9]))  # [2. 3.]
```

However, this does not work when numbers and objects are mixed:

```
print(np.sqrt([4, A()]))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-0c4201337685> in <module>()
----> 1 print(np.sqrt([4, A()]))

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```

This happens because the `dtype` of the heterogenous array is `object` and numpy functions broadcast by calling a method of the same name on each object, but numbers do not have methods with these names.

How do I work around this?

Comment: Warning: using numpy objects with custom objects is likely to be worse in terms of performance than a pure list.

Comment: The delegation to `sqrt` method is caused by the `object` dtype.  So all elements of the array have to have method.  An object dtype of pure numbers would have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the efficiency, but as a work around, you can use boolean indexing created with `map` and `isinstance` and then apply to both slices the same operation, changing the type of the element that are not of class `A` to be able to use the `numpy` method.

```
ar = np.array([4, A(), A(), 9.])
ar_t = np.array(list(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, A), ar)))

ar[~ar_t] = np.sqrt(ar[~ar_t].astype(float)) 
ar[ar_t] = np.sqrt(ar[ar_t])

print(ar)
# array([2.0, 1.414, 1.414, 3.0], dtype=object)
```

Note: in the `astype`, I used `float`, but not sure it will be good for your requirement